# how to convert java (awt) code into jsp code

Tags: java, jsp, awt

i have the following java (awt) code and i want to convert it in jsp.can any one tell me how do i do this?
my java class is `StackedBarChart1.java`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItem;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.GradientPaintTransformType;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.StandardGradientPaintTransformer;

public class StackedBarChart1 extends ApplicationFrame {

    StackedBarChart1(String titel) {
        super(titel);

        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 500));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        result.addValue(20.3, "Category 1 (D)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(27.2, "Category 1 (D)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(19.7, "Category 1 (D)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(20.7, "Category 1 (D)", "Apr 08");
        result.addValue(19.4, "Category 1 (E)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(10.9, "Category 1 (E)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(18.4, "Category 1 (E)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(12.4, "Category 1 (E)", "Apr 08");
        result.addValue(16.5, "Category 1 (W)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(15.9, "Category 1 (W)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(16.1, "Category 1 (W)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Category 1 (W)", "Apr 08");


        result.addValue(23.3, "Category 2 (D)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(16.2, "Category 2 (D)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(28.7, "Category 2 (D)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(22.7, "Category 2 (D)", "Apr 08");
        result.addValue(12.7, "Category 2 (E)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(17.9, "Category 2 (E)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(12.6, "Category 2 (E)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(14.6, "Category 2 (E)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(15.4, "Category 2 (W)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(21.0, "Category 2 (W)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(11.1, "Category 2 (W)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(16.1, "Category 2 (W)", "Apr 08");


        result.addValue(11.9, "Category 3 (D)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(31.0, "Category 3 (D)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(22.7, "Category 3 (D)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(18.7, "Category 3 (D)", "Apr 08");
        result.addValue(15.3, "Category 3 (E)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Category 3 (E)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(25.3, "Category 3 (E)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(16.3, "Category 3 (E)", "Apr 08");
        result.addValue(23.9, "Category 3 (W)", "Jan 08");
        result.addValue(19.0, "Category 3 (W)", "Feb 08");
        result.addValue(10.1, "Category 3 (W)", "Mar 08");
        result.addValue(18.1, "Category 3 (W)", "Apr 08");


        return result;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Referral Click Analysis (Stacked Bar Chart)", "Category", "Value", dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(249, 231, 236));

        GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
        KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");

        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 1 (D)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 1 (E)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 1 (W)", "G1");


        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 2 (D)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 2 (E)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 2 (W)", "G2");


        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 3 (D)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 3 (E)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Category 3 (W)", "G3");

        renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);


        renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);
        Paint p1 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(16, 89, 172), 0.0f, 0.0f, new
                                              Color(201, 201, 244));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, p1);

        Paint p2 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(10, 144, 40), 0.0f, 0.0f, new
                                              Color(160, 240, 180));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(7, p2);

        Paint p3 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(255, 35, 35), 0.0f, 0.0f, new
                                              Color(255, 180, 180));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p3);


        renderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(
                new StandardGradientPaintTransformer
                      (GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL));

        SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Category / Month");
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Category 1");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Category 2");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Category 3");

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setFixedLegendItems(createLegendItems());
        return chart;
    }

    private LegendItemCollection createLegendItems() {
        LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();
        LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("D", "D", "D", "D",
                new Rectangle(10, 10), new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f,
                new Color(16, 89, 172), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(201, 201, 244)));
        LegendItem item2 = new LegendItem("E", "E", "E", "E",
                new Rectangle(10, 10), new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f,
                new Color(10, 144, 40), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(160, 240, 180)));
        LegendItem item3 = new LegendItem("W", "W", "W", "W",
                new Rectangle(10, 10), new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f,
                new Color(255, 35, 35), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(255, 180, 180)));

        result.add(item1);
        result.add(item2);
        result.add(item3);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final StackedBarChart1 demo = new StackedBarChart1("Referral Click Analysis ");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSP you can write any java code within `<% .. %>`. But you'd better not. Reuse your current class. You can import it with `<%@ page import=".." %>`. But again - you should avoid writing any java code in the JSP. So you'd better do this in a servlet (where you can import your existing class)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, Bozho's answer is correct, but this won't magically convert a desktop AWT application into a web application. There's no simple way to get convert an AWT desktop app into a web app.

You really have two options:

1) Look into applets as a way to embed your app into a web page.

2) Translate your AWT code into some web-app UI technology like Google Web Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple actually.., save the generated JFreeChart object as an image (gif, jpg) in your webapp context path, then serve the image from your jsp.

You are done.